# How to get Unique CID and Avatar from this table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get unique CID's from this table. If there are 2 logins I still want to get only 1 row. Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT  distinct  [s1FirstName]
          ,[s1MiddleName]
          ,[s1LastName] 
          , [s1CIDNumber]         
          ,Login_Name  
      FROM [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblSurvey] s
    where s.survey_dt>='1/1/1'
    AND 
    s.survey_dt<='1/1/2099'
    AND
    s1CIDNumber<>''
```

The problem with above code is it will return multiple rows for different Login_Names. I just want to show 1 Login_Name  per unique CID.

```
order by s1CIDNumber
```

I believe I need a self join but I cannot figure it out.

[image]

Comment: How do you determine which Login_Name to show?  For s1CIDNumber 4245, there is Sasane and Sasanp.  What makes either one, the correct one?

Comment: that is not important in this case. Any login which is attached to that CID. So if logina and loginB attached to CID ust show one of them(or preferably if doableshow one which have the ealiest Suevey_DT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with x as 
(select row_number() over(partition by s1CIDNumber order by Suevey_DT) as rn, *
 from [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblSurvey])
select x.* --add any other columns from tblusers as needed
from x join tblUsers t 
on t.loginname = x.loginname
where x.rn = 1
```

You can use a `row_number()` function to only select 1 row per login. You can change the partitioning and order conditions if needed.

Comment: This looks correct, with changing the `ORDER BY` in the `PARTITION` to have the earlier Survey_DT according to his comment.

Comment: the only bad thing about this code and that is my bad infact , is don't understand what partition by s1CIDNumber order by login_name does. :)

Comment: partition by a column means it creates rownumbers per that columns with the ordering condition specified. The default ordering is ascending.

Comment: Result is promising but how can I use these results as a table. currently this returns firstName, LastName, CID , LoginName, How can I join this with other tables.

Comment: this will have all the columns + the rownumber which we created. You can join it on other tables just like any other table.

Comment: I tried:

`select m.s1CIDNumber  from 
(with x as 
(select row_number() over(partition by s1CIDNumber order by Survey_DT) as rn, s1CIDNumber as s1CIDNumber
 from [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblSurvey] s )
select * from x where rn = 1 )  m`

Comment: No..you should do `with x as 
(select row_number() over(partition by s1CIDNumber order by Suevey_DT) as rn, *
 from [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblSurvey])
select s1cidnumber from x where rn = 1`

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not following you , can you please update your answer and provide an example of how to join  results of your query to a table called tblUsers?

Comment: sure..on which column in `tblusers` should it be joined?

Comment: LoginName both tables have LoginName

Comment: modified it.please check

Comment: Thanks for your comment now  it is 80% clear. One last question if you don't mind.  How can I group by Login_Name  For s1CIdNumber?